# Using F# scripts like php instead of with asp.net core

Tags: php, f#

So I was wondering if you could use F# with fsi.exe to run server side scripts to serve html pages. Basically, could you use it like php? If you can, would it be very practical to use it like that? Also, even if this is not very practical, I would be interested in if this would somehow be possible.

Comment: Looked at https://safe-stack.github.io/ ? F# doesn't lend itself to PHP look and feel (white space has meaning) but the elm architecture approach is popular and better IMHO. Using Fable you can transpile F# to JavaScript for client side rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP and for that matter Classic ASP pages on a web site typically map one-to-one to script files on the file system on a web server.

If you implement ASP.Net's [IHttpHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler?view=netframework-4.8) you could execute F# scripts on the file system in response to HTTP requests. The IHttpHandler's ProcessRequest method passes a [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8) instance which could be used for reading the Request arguments and setting the Response. This could be passed to a well-known function implemented, say "handler", in the F# script.

```
type HttpHandler() =
  interface IHttpHandler with
    member this.ProcessRequest(context:HttpContext) =
      let localpath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath)
      let a = compile localpath // where compile creates an assembly from an fsx file
      let mi = getHandler a // where getHandler gets a function using reflection
      mi.Invoke(null, [|context|])
```

The F# Compiler Services provides [FSharperChecker](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/reference/fsharp-compiler-sourcecodeservices-fsharpchecker.html) API which could be used to compile F# script files to dynamic assemblies.

```
let compile path =        
    let checker = FSharpChecker.Create()
    let errors, exitCode, dynamicAssembly = 
        checker.CompileToDynamicAssembly([| "-o"; path; "-a"; path |], execute=None)
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
    dynamicAssembly
```

The dynamic assemblies could then be used to invoke functions via reflection, passing the HttpContext value.

```
  let getHandler a =
    a.GetTypes() |> Seq.pick (fun ty ->
      match ty.GetMethod("handler", [|typeof<System.Web.HttpContext>|]) with
      | null -> None
      | mi -> Some mi
    )
```

So that your script file might look something like this:

```
let handler (context:System.Web.HttpContext) =
  context.Response.Write("Hello World")
```

Finally there are a plethora of F# DSLS for generating HTML from code, I have a simple one called [FsHtml](https://github.com/ptrelford/FsHtml).

Comment: Just to touch on another part of my question, would it be practical to use this approach (or any approach that uses F# like php or classic asp) in the real world? Or would it make more sense to go with something like asp.net core?

Comment: Practicality would probably depend on the kind of projects you are working on and the make up of your team. For example it might work well for heavy data and compute tasks with a capable team.

Answer (score 1):

Giraffe with the Razor view engine might be the best fit for what you're after: https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe.Razor

It provides a nice way to define API routes functionally and a nice clean syntax for HTML templates.

It does use asp.net core though - I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by avoiding this so apologies if my answer is a little off-target.

You can compile .fsx scripts with Fable (see here: https://axxes.com/en/net/compiling-f-scripts-with-fable-2-2/) as `Just another metaprogrammer` has mentioned, though personally it's not my preferred approach (I'm happy with .fs) and I'd argue that it's more akin to react / jsx since it's client side and uses react under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not really trying to achieve anything specific, I am more so curious if it was possible to run f# files as you would run php files while I do know this might not be very practical or as fast as using asp.net core.